# Using industrial_robot_client without simple_message

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am implementing the Robot Driver specification ([link](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Industrial_Robot_Driver_Spec)), however the "reference" `JointTrajectoryDownloader` implementation assumes you are communicating with a robot that uses the `simple_message` protocol. My robot does not communicate using `simple_messages`, it communicates using ordinary ROS topics and messages.

The usage of `simple_message` protocol is very deeply embedded into the `JointTrajectoryDownloader` and `JointTrajectoryInterface` classes. **What is the best way to use the `JointTrajectoryDownloader` library on a robot that does *not* use  `simple_message` for communication?**

Thanks,
Bart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191782/using-industrial_robot_client-without-simple_message/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2014-09-04**:
The link you provided is to the industrial_robot_client wiki...not a specification (is this what you meant)?

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-09-04**:
If you don't want to use the simple_message protocol, do you really need to use the industrial_robot_client, then?. What's the actual problem you'd like to solve, send joint trajectories to your robot and read state feedback?

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-09-04**:
Hi Adolfo, I don't strictly need to use it, but apart from the use of `simple_message` as a communication method it actually quite closely fits my requirements. From my point of view it makes little sense to do effectively a 'copy-and-paste' programming job.

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-09-04**:
sedwards: link has been updated

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-09-04**:
Conversely, I did investigate writing a *receiver* for `simple_message`, but I could not find any documentation or tutorials on how to do so. Is this a gap in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The specification you reference simply outlines the ROS API for ROS-Industrial.  The industrial_robot_client library is a set of nodes that adheres to that spec and provides a bridge to robot controllers via simple_message.  It was never meant to bridge from one ROS API to another...since a robot that could already speak ROS messages should be simple to modify/adapt.
I do not think you can easily utilize the industrial_robot_client nodes to bridge between ROS APIs, nor would I recommend you do that.
If you still would like to create a receiver for simple_message, then you can find examples in the vendor packages ( [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/blob/hydro-devel/abb_driver/rapid/ROS_motionServer.mod).  These files are written in a controller specific language, RAPID, but it's readable enough to get the idea.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-09-08**:
Thanks for that info, it looks like I will stick to writing my own interface with MoveIt.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-09-09**:
Consider taking a look at the ros_control project. It offers controllers compatible with MoveIt!, and a Gazebo backend. You would have to expose your hardware to ros_control yourself, but the overhead is much lower than doing it all from scratch.

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-09-10**:
Thanks Adolfo. I am presently pursuing this line of development.